# Create Office 365 user in Azure B2C using invitation api in microsoft graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, azure-ad-b2c

I need to register office 365 users residing in another Azure AD to be created programmatically using microsoft graph API into Azure AD B2C directory. I am successful in creating and logging into local accounts but creating external identity users hasn't been successful. The microsoft documentation is verbose too for this context. The scenario is as under.

1. Invited the user using **invitation API**.
2. User accepts the invitation received in their email and gets redirected to grant permission screen for the app, and then lands on the redirect url.
3. The user can be seen in Azure B2C users as **invited** and then **external azure ad** after invitation acceptance

Problem:

1. The same user can't login using the Signin flow that works for the local accounts. I noticed the **signInIssuerId** is also null for this user. The error received states please sign up user first/no account found.

I understand there is some disconnection behind where the invitation is sent but the user is not signed up from the graph api. How can this be achieved? I would hate to know if that would be possible only using IDEF / custom policies

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that these are social/federated users, not local ones.

You need to use the "SocialAndLocalAccounts" policies in the [starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack).

Invitations via the API are for B2B users. This type of user is not supported in B2C.

For examples of B2C invitations, look [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples).

Comment: With the starter pack will the self sign up take place behind the scenses? Currently the user gets in B2C directory but the signinIssuerid is null which should have been the federated user email.

Comment: For federated, yes. Look at alternativeSecurityId.